# Create Pivot table from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert the data given here from:

[image: original_data]

to this:

[image: transformed_data]

where the numbers are Sales against each company.
How can I do this with Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

The `pivot` call will reshape the dataframe from rows to columns and `fillna(0)` will replace the empty cells with zero, finally `reset_index` will get rid of hierarchical column

```py
df.pivot(index='Month', columns='Company', values='Sales').fillna(0).reset_index()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
Company  Month  Apple    HP
0            1    8.0   0.0
1            2    8.0   0.0
2            3   14.0   0.0
3            4    3.0   0.0
4            5    4.0  10.0
5            6    3.0   9.0
6            7   14.0   9.0
7            8    0.0  10.0
8            9    0.0   3.0
9           10    0.0   4.0
```

**PS**: It is recommended to add your data as text while asking the question, we can not copy the contents from image.

Answer (score 1):

pandas' [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function is your friend. You can use it to group by month and company, and then rearrange to grouping by company (which appears as index) into columns:

```py
df.groupby(['Month', 'Company'])['Sales'].sum().unstack()
```

After the `groupby(['Month', 'Company'])['Sales'].sum()` you have companies as indices, therefore the use of `unstack()` to change them in to columns.